# How to get titles from a markdown and put them in an array in Python 2.7

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, markdown

I'm new to python, I'm trying to parse a markdown file, I want to put all the titles in one array, the blocks in an other array etc..
I used mistune but all I get is html text.
How can I do that ?

```
import mistune
import codecs
import re

path = 'exg.txt'

with codecs.open(path) as markdownFile:
    markdownFile = open(path, "r")
    mdText = markdownFile.read()


markdown = mistune.Markdown()
parsedText = markdown(mdText)
print parsedText
```

Comment: All you get is html because that is what mistune does, its a library for converting markdown to html

Comment: So I have to parse the html now in order to get headers and paragraphs etc..

Comment: Ah I see, so you would like the title elements from the html?

Comment: yes, and all other html components. I used regular expression and it worked !

Comment: So you are not looking for the titles, you are looking for something like this - "<h1>This is a title</h1>" in an array with all the other html blocks in another

Comment: I needed to get titles and paragraphs from a markdown file in order to do some NLP process. I converted the file to html then I parsed it using regex in python which gives a table as a result of the method re.findAll

Comment: I was thinking that mistune could do that but I was wrong. Thank you for pointing this out !